# コンソールアプリケーションで、別TaskからProcess.Startで処理が止まる

Tags: c#, 非同期

.NETフレームワークは4.0です。
コンソールアプリケーションで以下のメソッドを実行すると、Convert内のProcess.Startで処理が停止してしまいます(例外の発生ではなく、次に進まなくなる)。
また、Process.Startでの外部アプリケーションの呼び出しには成功していて、タスクマネージャから確認すると処理も終わっています。
このメソッドをWindowsFormアプリケーションから呼び出すと、正常に終了します。

```
public CancellationTokenSource ConvertAsync<T>(object obj,string[]　files,Listener listener){
    var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var task = new Task(
        ()=>{
             try{
                Task convertedTask = null;
                Action<object> action = new Action<object>((obj) => {
                    try{                                                    
                        listener.oneFile(obj);
                        return;
                    } catch (Exception ex2) {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex2);
                        return;
                }});
                foreach (var file in files) {

                    if(cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)return;
                    Debug.WriteLine("before:"+file);
                    var converted =Convert(obj,file);/* <-ここでProcess.Start()呼び出し*/
                    Debug.WriteLine("after:"+converted);
                    if(converted==null)break;

                    if(convertedTask==null){
                        convertedTask = new Task(action,ab,cancellation.Token);
                        convertedTask.Start();
                    }else{
                        convertedTask = convertedTask.ContinueWith((arg) => action(converted),cancellation.Token);
                    }
                }
                if(convertedTask!=null)convertedTask.Wait();
                listener.allDone();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                return;
            }

    },cancellation.Token);
    task.Start();
    return cancellation;
}
```

以上、ご教授いただければ幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: コード内、new Task(action,ab,cancellation.Token);ではなく、new Task(action,converted,cancellation.Token);です。また、fileが3回目の時に停止します。

Comment: ３回目のfileをfilesから除外すると、停止は起こらないのでしょうか？　もしそうなら、３回目のfileの内容を検討すべきだと思います。

Comment: どのfileを選択しても、3回目には必ず停止してしまいます。また、WindowsFormアプリケーションから呼び出すと、同じfileを選択しても、最後まで実行されます。

Comment: 検証したところ、convertedTask.Start()をコメントアウトするとconvertedTask.Wait()まで実行されるので、TaskとProcessの組み合わせが悪そうです。Task.ContinueWithの指定方法が悪いのか(そもそも、今回のような使い方はタブーなのでしょうか)、convertedTaskでは重い作業をさせない方がいいのか、恥ずかしながら勉強不足で恐縮ですが、その点も含めてご指摘いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

開示していない情報でしたが、コンソールアプリケーション側ではConvertAsyncを呼び出した後、Console.ReadLine()で待機していました。
しかし、下記のように返り値をTaskに変更し、コンソールアプリケーション側でTask.Wait()で待機した所、正常終了するようになりました。原因は未だに不明です。

```
public Task ConvertAsync<T>(object obj,string[]　files,Listener listener){
    var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var task = new Task(
        ()=>{
             try{
                Task convertedTask = null;
                Action<object> action = new Action<object>((obj) => {
                    try{                                                    
                        listener.oneFile(obj);
                        return;
                    } catch (Exception ex2) {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex2);
                        return;
                }});
                foreach (var file in files) {

                    if(cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)return;
                    Debug.WriteLine("before:"+file);
                    var converted =Convert(obj,file);/* <-ここでProcess.Start()呼び出し*/
                    Debug.WriteLine("after:"+converted);
                    if(converted==null)break;

                    if(convertedTask==null){
                        convertedTask = new Task(action,converted,cancellation.Token);
                        convertedTask.Start();
                    }else{
                        convertedTask = convertedTask.ContinueWith((arg) => action(converted),cancellation.Token);
                    }
                }
                if(convertedTask!=null)convertedTask.Wait();
                listener.allDone();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                return;
            }

    },cancellation.Token);
    task.Start();
    return task;
}
```